# Azure Service Bus - Subscribe multiple topics inside the same worker/hosted service

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

we have a scenario where we must integrate requests with the same destination system, which exposes its operations with REST APIs (provided by a third party, most likely not Azure). So this is a scenario where n messages are mapped in n actions on the same destination system. There is no multicast or broadcast.

So we are considering Service Bus to achieve this, based on previous experiences on other use cases, and taking advantage of dead letter mechanism among other things.

We need to integrate 6 or 7 different actions with the 3rd party. So on Service Bus we can achieve this by creating 1 topic per action, and this is important because the data that travels on the message is different from action to action.

But we are facing a situation when consuming topics. We are able to have an hosted service in Azure (App Service) that listens on a specific topic and does its stuff.

But since we are trying to listen on several topics, we would like to avoid writing and deploying multiple app services, we would like (if possible) to have a single app service where we 'trigger' each ServiceBusProcessor (one per topic) and even though they all rely on the limits of the app service itself, each processor is independent and is listening on its topic in parallel and processing.

I'll share a code sample below of our hosted service, but we found out two options, we would like to have opinions:
Option 1: we send all messages to the same topic, then by using filters we determine which is the appropriate action. This would make code simple, but it would put all messages on the same 'line' which would make the topic an all purpose topic, which seems wrong
Option 2: based on our sample below, which represents a single hosted service which listens on a single topic, we would break it and inject a List of listeners that implement the same interface, and each one of them would be working independently on its topic and its message. We are not sure if this is feasible and if it works properly, because the app service would have to handle multiple ServiceBusProcessors side by side.

We'd like to know if we are missing some option, or if there is any other better way to achieve this. Hope I've explained it well.

I send below a sample of our hosted service. Thanks a lot.

```
public class MyService : IHostedService, IMyService
    {
        private ILogger<MyService> _logger;

        public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient("connectionString");

            ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor("topicName", "subscriptionName");
            
            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += ProcessMessageAsync;
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessErrorAsync;

            _logger.LogInformation("Listener initialized");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task ProcessMessageAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            var body = args.Message.Body;

            //  Do stuff with this body...

            await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
        }

        public Task ProcessErrorAsync(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error ocurred: {args.Exception.ToString()} with message: {args.Exception.Message}");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Then at ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
```

So, following option 2, the sample above would be transformed in the following, considering 2 listeners:

```
public interface IMyService
    {

    }

    public interface IMyListener
    {
        Task Initialize();

        Task ProcessMessageAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args);

        Task ProcessErrorAsync(ProcessErrorEventArgs args);
    }

    public class BaseListener
    {
        private string _connectionString;
        private string _topicName;
        private string _subscriptionName;
        private ILogger<BaseListener> _logger;

        public BaseListener(ILogger<BaseListener> logger, string connectionString, string topicName, string subscriptionName)
        {
            this._connectionString = connectionString;
            this._topicName = topicName;
            this._subscriptionName = subscriptionName;
            this._logger = logger;
        }

        public Task Initialize()
        {
            ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(this._connectionString);

            ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(this._topicName, this._subscriptionName);

            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += ProcessMessageAsync;
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessErrorAsync;

            _logger.LogInformation("Listener initialized");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task ProcessMessageAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            var body = args.Message.Body;

            //  Do stuff with this body...

            await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
        }

        public Task ProcessErrorAsync(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public class MyListener1: BaseListener, IMyListener
    {
        public MyListener1(ILogger<MyListener1> logger) : base(logger, "connectionString", "topic1", "subscription")
        {

        }
    }

    public class MyListener2 : BaseListener, IMyListener
    {
        public MyListener2(ILogger<MyListener2> logger) : base(logger, "connectionString", "topic2", "subscription")
        {

        }
    }

    public class MyService : IHostedService, IMyService
    {
        private ILogger<MyService> _logger;
        private IEnumerable<IMyListener> _listeners;

        public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger, IEnumerable<IMyListener> listeners)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _listeners = listeners;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach(var listener in this._listeners)
            {
                listener.Initialize();
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("Listeners initialized");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

And on ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
services.AddSingleton<IMyListener, MyListener1>();
services.AddSingleton<IMyListener, MyListener2>();
```

Comment: Did you ever decide on a solution on this?